# @HystrixCommand + Inject Errors with Aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, hystrix

We're using Hystrix like so:

```
@HystrixCommand(...)
public void someOperation() {
    ...
}
```

This works great. We'd like to be able to inject errors and sleeps for testing within these methods and we're trying to create an `@Aspect` for just this purpose:

```
@Before("execution(* our.package.OurClass.someOperation(..))")
public void causeTrouble() {
    ...
}
```

The issue we're seeing is that our advice is running before the Hystrix advice (`HystrixCommandAspect`) which means that sleeps and exceptions we inject in are treated differently and not handled by Hystrix. Is there a way to ensure our aspect runs inside the Hystrix aspect? I've tried the ordering suggestions in the spring documentation without any luck (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering). Is there another approach to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What order have you tried? You would also have to order the hysterix aspect else it won't work. Ordered aspects always run before unordered aspects, so if you don't explictly declare an order for that also it won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've tried `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` and implementing `Ordered` on my aspect. The hystrix aspect is unordered so it makes sense why my aspect is being called first no matter what precedence I choose. It sounds like the hystrix aspect needs `Order(0)` to have an explict order and let other aspect choose if they want to be inside or outside. Thanks.

Comment: Just adding the hysterix aspect with an order should fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control it. It's declared here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/3fb26f69e5a1b671f9d2557b203b75537e7d1b89/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCircuitBreakerConfiguration.java#L58. So I'll need to create a pull request for them.

Comment: No you don't... Just create a bean definition matching that one and put an order on it, that will override the one from the regular configuration.